# Problem with "while read" and paste

Tags: bash, paste

I have 69 files called `*.sites.pi`. For instance, `OC9.sites.pi`, `cu27.sites.pi`, etc.

The prefix of each file (that is before the .sites.pi) is in a file called `ind_list`.

```
$ cat ind_list
OC9
Ocu27
...
```

I want to merge the third columns of all these files together.

I tried :

```
while read i
do
    paste <(cut -f3 $i.sites.pi) >> output
done < ind_list
```

But it doesn't work. How can I make it work?

Comment: what do you mean with merge? print all the columns side by side or one after the other? You are currently pasting one single thing, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes I want to print the columns side by side.

Comment: Does your command have the expected behaviour outside of your loop ? i.e. is `paste <(cut -f3 OC9.sites.pi) >> output` correct ?

Comment: Yes it works ! The problem comes with the while read loop...

Comment: I could do it that way and it works: `paste <(cut -f3 Ocu27.sites.pi) <(cut -f3 OS10.sites.pi) <(cut -f3 OC9.sites.pi) > output`
But writing 69 times the "<(cut -f3 OC9.sites.pi)" part is super annoying !!!

Comment: I can imagine that it can be anoying :p How is it not working in your loop then ? Bad display ? Do you get an error ? maybe the behaviour of `paste` is different if you write `paste <(cut -f3 Ocu27.sites.pi) <(cut -f3 OS10.sites.pi) >output` and `paste <(cut -f3 Ocu27.sites.pi) >>output ; paste <(cut -f3 OS10.sites.pi) >>output`

Comment: I tried them both. I had the feeling that the `>output` was replacing the output that's why I tried with `>>`

Answer (score 4):

Pasting files needs to have all the elements given at the same time to `paste`. Since you are reading a file, you then need to firstly store the content somewhere -in a temp file, for example- so that you can then `paste` them together.

So I suggest something like this:

```
i=1
while read -r file
do
    awk '{print $3}' "$file" > file.$i
    ((i++))
done < ind_list
```

Now you have many `file.XX` files with the 3rd column of the file.

Then, just use [something like this, where glenn jackman enlightens us](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17075524/1983854):

```
paste -d " " file.{1..69} > output
```

And then you can clean all the temp files by saying `rm file{1..69}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working !! Just needed to change `file{1..69}` to `file.{1..69}`

Comment: @user236152 nice to read that! Remember you can accept any of the answers that helped you to solve the problem (I like them all !)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a terminal to test my answer, so I'll try a blind guess.

I'd think there might be a difference in behaviour between

```
paste <(cut -f3 Ocu27.sites.pi) <(cut -f3 OS10.sites.pi) >output
```

and

```
paste <(cut -f3 Ocu27.sites.pi) >>output
paste <(cut -f3 OS10.sites.pi) >>output
```

To address that, you could change your original loop to :

```
while read i
do
    arguments="$arguments <(cut -f3 $i.sites.pi)"
done < ind_list
eval "paste $arguments >output"
```

Another benefit from this is that you execute `paste` only once at the end of your loop, and could thus have some performance improvement compared to computing the pasting at each iteration of your loop

Comment: I like this solution, +1. I would maybe use `args=$(awk '{printf "<(cut -f3 %s) ", $1})' ind_list` to create the string to make it fancier.

Comment: @fedorqui agreed, the `awk` bit looks cooler than the loop:)

Comment: In general, when is about just processing text alone, `awk` or `sed` suffice. I use bash loops if I want to perform something extra, like calling an external command, etc.

Answer (score 0):

### Using `cat` and `awk`

```
cat ind_list | xargs -i'{}' awk '{print $3}' "{}.sites.pi" > output
```

---

#### Example

*Input files*

`cat OC8.sites.pi`

```
foo bar foobar
```

`cat OC9.sites.pi`

```
foo bar foobar
```

`cat Ocu27.sites.pi`

```
foobar foo bar
```

`cat ind_list`

```
OC8
OC9
Ocu27
```

*The command*

```
cat ind_list | xargs -i'{}' awk '{print $3}' "{}.sites.pi" > output
```

*The output file*

`cat output`

```
foobar
foobar
bar
```